# Replacing numbers with their respective strings in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am a newbie in bash/awk programming and I have a file looks like this:

```
1   10032154    10032154    A   C   Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9    criteria_provided,_single_submitter Benign  .   1
1   10032184    10032184    A   G   Retinal_dystrophy|Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9|not_provided criteria_provided,_multiple_submitters,_no_conflicts    Pathogenic/Likely_pathogenic    .   1,4
1   10032209    10032209    G   A   not_provided    criteria_provided,_single_submitter Likely_benign   .   8,64,512
```

**With awk**, I want to change the numbers in the last column ($10) with their descriptions. I assigned the numbers and their definitions in two different arrays. The way I was thinking was to change these numbers by iterating the two array together. Here, 0 is "unknown", 1 is "germline", 4 is "somatic" and goes on.

```
z=(0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 1073741824)
t=("unknown" "germline" "somatic" "inherited" "paternal" "maternal" "de-novo" "biparental" "uniparental" "not-tested" "tested-inconclusive" "not-reported" "other")

number=$(IFS=,; echo "${z[*]}")
def=$(IFS=,; echo "${t[*]}")
    
awk -v a="$number" -v b="${def}" 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } /#/ {next} 
{
    x=split(a, e, /,/)
    y=split(b, f, /,/)
    
    delete c
    m=split($10, c, /,/)
    for (i=1; i<=m; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=x; j++) {
            if (c[i]==e[j]) {
                c[i]=f[j]
            }
        }
        $10+=sprintf("%s, ",c[i])
    }
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10
}' input.vcf > output.vcf
```

The output should look like this:

```
1   10032154    10032154    A   C   Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9    criteria_provided,_single_submitter Benign  .   germline
1   10032184    10032184    A   G   Retinal_dystrophy|Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9|not_provided criteria_provided,_multiple_submitters,_no_conflicts    Pathogenic/Likely_pathogenic    .   germline,paternal
1   10032209    10032209    G   A   not_provided    criteria_provided,_single_submitter Likely_benign   .   paternal,biparental,tested-inconclusive
```

I would be so glad if you could help me!

All the best

Comment: you may want to check `split()` to get the values of the last field ($NF) as well to "prepare" the matching. What have you tried?

Comment: please update the question with the `awk` code you've tried

Comment: Hey, I added the code I've tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't really need to define the lists of numbers and names as 2 shell arrays for some other reason:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 1073741824",nrsArr)
    split("unknown germline somatic inherited paternal maternal de-novo biparental uniparental not-tested tested-inconclusive not-reported other",namesArr)
    for (i in nrsArr) {
        nr2name[nrsArr[i]] = namesArr[i]
    }
}
!/#/ {
    n = split($NF,nrs,/,/)
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,"")
    printf "%s", $0
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", nr2name[nrs[i]], (i<n ? "," : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.vcf
1   10032154    10032154    A   C   Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9    criteria_provided,_single_submitter Benign  .   germline
1   10032184    10032184    A   G   Retinal_dystrophy|Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9|not_provided criteria_provided,_multiple_submitters,_no_conflicts    Pathogenic/Likely_pathogenic    .   germline,inherited
1   10032209    10032209    G   A   not_provided    criteria_provided,_single_submitter Likely_benign   .   paternal,biparental,tested-inconclusive
```

The above preserves whatever white space you had in your input file in case that matters.

Answer (score 5):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
z=(0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 1073741824)
t=("unknown" "germline" "somatic" "inherited" "paternal" "maternal" "de-novo" "biparental" "uniparental" "not-tested" "tested-inconclusive" "not-reported" "other")

awk -v z="${z[*]}" -v t="${t[*]}" '
BEGIN {
   split(z, zarr)
   split(t, tarr)
   for (i=1; i in zarr; ++i)
      map[zarr[i]] = tarr[i]
}
{
   split($NF, arr, /,/)
   s = ""
   for (i=1; i in arr; ++i)
      s = s (i == 1 ? "" : ",") map[arr[i]]
   $NF = s;
}
1
' file
```

btw number `4` is mapped to `inherited` not `paternal` as you have in your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use this short Perl in-line script:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '
BEGIN {
    @keys = qw( 0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 1073741824 );
    @vals = qw( unknown germline somatic inherited paternal maternal de-novo biparental uniparental not-tested tested-inconclusive not-reported other );
    %val = map { $keys[$_] => $vals[$_] } 0..$#keys;
}
print join "\t", @F[0..8], ( join ",", map { $val{$_} } split /,/, $F[9] );
' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl script uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\t/'` : Split into `@F` on TAB, rather than on whitespace.

`%val = map { $keys[$_] => $vals[$_] } 0..$#keys;` : Create `%val` - a hash lookup table with keys = numeric codes and values = mutation/variant types.

Note that in Perl, arrays are 0-indexed.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- OP has confirmed beforehand that the `z` and `t` arrays are valid (eg, same number of elements in both arrays)
- OP may want to (dynamically) change the contents of the `z` and `t` arrays so we'll leave the array assignments at the `bash` level (ie, won't hardcode inside of `awk`)
- the substitution strings could contain white space so we'll keep OP's current method of building comma-delimited strings (from the `z` and `t`) arrays; also assumes replacement strings do not contain commas; this should simplify parsing of the replacement strings within `awk`
- while OP has explicitly coded for (`awk`) field #10, we'll assume this number could change; we'll focus on processing the `last field` in a row

Small change to initialization code:

```
# original arrays

z=(0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 1073741824)
t=("unknown" "germline" "somatic" "inherited" "paternal" "maternal" "de-novo" "biparental" "uniparental" "not-tested" "tested-inconclusive" "not-reported" "other")

# renamed variables (format: x,y,z,...)

nums=$(IFS=,; echo "${z[*]}")
alphas=$(IFS=,; echo "${t[*]}")
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v nums="${nums}" -v alphas="${alphas}" '        # pass comma-delimited variables to awk

BEGIN     { OFS="\t"                                 # copied from original code:w
            n=split(nums,num,/,/)                    # split comma-delimted variables
            a=split(alphas,alpha,/,/)                # into arrays
          }

/#/       { next }                                   # copied from original code

          { l=split($NF,lastf,/,/)                   # split the last (comma-delimited) field
            $NF=""                                   # clear the last field
            pfx=""                                   # initialize our prefix string

            for (i=1; i<=l; i++)                     # loop through entries in the last field
                for (j=1; j<=n; j++)                 # loop through array of numbers
                    if ( lastf[i] == num[j] )        # if array entries match ...
                       { $NF= $NF pfx alpha[j]       # append the associated alpha to the last field
                         pfx=","                     # set the prefix to "," for the next item
                         break                       # break out one level to process next entry in the last field
                       }
          }

          { print }                                  # print the current line (with modified last field)
' input.vcf
```

The above generates:

```
1       10032154        10032154        A       C       Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9    criteria_provided,_single_submitter  Benign  .       germline
1       10032184        10032184        A       G       Retinal_dystrophy|Leber_congenital_amaurosis_9|not_provided  criteria_provided,_multiple_submitters,_no_conflicts    Pathogenic/Likely_pathogenic.germline,inherited
1       10032209        10032209        G       A       not_provided    criteria_provided,_single_submitter  Likely_benign   .       paternal,biparental,tested-inconclusive
```

Comment: Never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code.